# Breaker to outdoor Sub panel keep tripping

Tags: electrical, gfci, outdoor, subpanel

Need help with my outdoor kitchen fridge.

A 20 amp fuse at the main box goes takes a 10/2 w/ground wire to a sub panel.
The sub panel has two 15 amp breakers circuit one goes to a storage shed via a 12/2 UF rated buried line that only has a 100 watt light, a GFCI outlet.
Circuit two has the same 12/2 w/ground UF buried attached to a GFCI that has the mini fridge, two outlets that are wired to the load side of the GFCI.

The problem is that the breaker to leg two, and the breaker in the main box keep tripping.  But, they don't trip when I reset them.  They both trip, later, hours later.  I reset both last night at about 9:00 checked to make sure it was live at 10:30, this morning BOTH had tripped.  I have checked one of the outlets, it had a wire that had been nicked.  I rewired the outlet and reinstalled the outlet.

I have a GFCI tester and the GFCI appears to be wired correctly, I tested the gfci with the tester ad it trips the gfci.

So:

1. Why  is this happening?
2. Why doesn't the GFCI trip?
3. How do I fix this?

Comment: GFCI only trips on short to ground. A normal breaker trips on overcurrent, which may be a short from hot to _neutral_. You need to figure out what's drawing an unreasonable amount of power and fix it. Disconnect the fridge and see if the breaker stays set; if so you may need a new compressor motor.

Comment: I did disconnect the fridge and put on a lamp 100w blub and it tripped.  Also, put the fridge on a different circuit, same GFCI type set up and it held.  The fridge is new, I'm pretty sure it's not the fridge.  Why is the fuse delayed,

Comment: In that case, unplug EVERYTHING and see if it still trips. If it does you have a wiring problem. If not do a search (either linear or binary) for the one thing that trips it when present but lets it run when absent, and fix that.

Comment: Ok, I did unplug everything and it still tripped.  So, I have a wiring problem.  Now what?  Do I pull every outlet and check them.  How can I check the buried line?  I don't want to pull the line up unless I have to.

Comment: The problem, if there's a single problem, is in the branch whose load breaker is tripping. isolate that, and recheck every connection. If you still can't find the problem, disconnect and cap things until the breaker stops blowing, then carefully recheck/redo everything downstream from the last point you disconnected. Lather, rinse, repeat if necessary, and try not to burn down the shed in the meantime.

Comment: Divide and conquer. Reduce the problem to smaller problems.

Comment: Do you have an ammeter? Could be a high impedance short-circuit, or loose connection causing heating. That might explain the delay. It could also be a low impedance short-circuit, within a device that only comes on from time to time.

Comment: I have a digital multi-meter that has an amp meter in it.  How do I configure the wires to test for a high-impedance short circuit. If I am testing impedance, isn't this measured in ohms?

Comment: Have you done any lawn maintenance recently, like install a new metal border around the driveway, flower beds, ect.  If this is something new always look at what has changed first.

Comment: No Lawn Maintenance has been done, and the UF wire is new.

Comment: @ScottShook If you measure the current being drawn by the circuit, it might show an unexpectedly high draw. This could indicate a high impedance short-circuit.

Comment: @Scott Shook Probably have stagnant water trapped in pipe with nicked wires. The water creates a slow fault to ground.